# How to pass value in post method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to download a file from the folder using nodejs. Everything works fine while using get method. But when i am trying to send file name as parameter in post method it shows "undefined".

```js
var download =req.body.download;

app.post("/hi", function (req, res)
 {
    res.download("./uploads/"+download+"");
});
```

> download is my parameter where i will pass file name

Comment: plz console download outside app.post and see the result

Comment: yes i have tried. its still shows undefined.  Have i done any mistake while initialising var?

Comment: no var is ok can u console req.body

Comment: "var download =req.body.download;"  should be just above to res.download.You have written it outside to app.post route, it should be inside.

Answer (score 5):

You should use middle-ware `body-parser` to parse parameters from request body and get it inside scope of your POST handler. To install body-parser module:

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Update your code like below:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/hi", function (req, res) {
    var download = req.body.download;
    res.download("./uploads/"+download+"");
});
```

And make a call to POST `/hi` with body json:

```
{
   "download": "test"
}
```

---

**UPDATED:**

From **Express 3**, `body-parser` middleware is attached (built-in) in express. So don't need to install it any more, just need to declare using module as code below:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

For reference: [Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could pass params like this:

```
app.post("/hi/:download", function (req, res) {
    var download = req.params.download;
    res.download("./uploads/"+download+"");
});
```

And it doesn't even have to be a POST request anymore, you can just use a GET request. Also you can ditch body-parser with this method.